# Using typescript-language-server through tramp can't find servers for typescript-mode

Tags: tramp, ssh, lsp-mode, lsp

I am trying to work remotely on a typescript project, with `lsp-mode` and `tramp`, through SSH.

I followed the documentation on lsp-mode web page to set up a remote client. Here is my config:

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  :commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
  :init
  (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")
  :bind (:map lsp-mode-map
         ("TAB" . completion-at-point))
  :config
  (lsp-enable-which-key-integration t))
(require 'lsp-mode)
(setq tramp-remote-path '(tramp-default-remote-path "~/.local/bin/" "/usr/local/bin/"))

(use-package typescript-mode
  :mode "\\.ts\\'"
  :hook (typescript-mode . lsp))
(require 'typescript-mode)

(lsp-register-client
    (make-lsp-client :new-connection (lsp-tramp-connection (list "typescript-language-server" "--stdio"))
                     :major-modes '(typescript-mode)
                     :remote? t
                     :server-id 'ts-ls))
```

And `typescript-language-server` is installed on my remote machine, version 0.8.1. I am able to use typescript with lsp-mode locally just fine. For that, I followed lsp documentation for setting up ts-ls. Still, I get the following error when I open a remote project:

> LSP :: There are no language servers supporting current mode
> `typescript-mode' registered with` lsp-mode'. This issue might be
> caused by:
>
> 1. The language you are trying to use does not have built-in support in `lsp-mode'. You must install the required support manually. Examples of this are` lsp-java' or `lsp-metals'.
> 2. The language server that you expect to run is not configured to run for major mode `typescript-mode'. You may check that by checking the` :major-modes' that are passed to `lsp-register-client'.
> 3. `lsp-mode' doesn't have any integration for the language behind` typescript-mode'. Refer to
>    https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/languages and
>    https://langserver.org/ .
> 4. You are over `tramp'. In this case follow https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/remote/.
> 5. You have disabled the `lsp-mode' clients for that file. (Check` lsp-enabled-clients' and `lsp-disabled-clients').

I think 1 does not apply to me since typescript is supported by lsp-mode. For 2, you can see that I added typescript-mode as major mode in my lsp-register-client. I have checked lsp-enabled-clients for point 5 and it was nil, which meant all were registered. For the point 3, I know lsp-mode has integration for typescript since I locally use it.

Only point remaining for me is 4, I guess. There I suspect my config I shared above might be wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hard to say, I don't use lsp-mode. Reading your conf, the entry `(setq tramp-remote-path '(tramp-default-remote-path "~/.local/bin/" "/usr/local/bin/"))` looks suspicious. I'd rather append your own settings, by something like `(setq tramp-remote-path (append tramp-remote-path '("~/.local/bin/")))`. `"/usr/local/bin/"`is already present.

Comment: And if this still doesn't work, please produce Tramp traces with `tramp-verbose` set to 6, and contact us via `tramp-devel@gnu.org`.

Comment: I can see that `typescript-language-server` binary is present in one of the directories in `tramp-remote-path`. (by checking `tramp` file inside my `.emacs.d`. I just can't figure out why lsp can't start this language server remotely for Typescript. I can use clangd for C++ over Tramp just fine. Typescript integration in lsp over Tramp is the issue. I suspect issue is on the lsp side.

Comment: Set `tramp-verbose` to 6, rerun your test, and send the resulting traces to the mail address above.